# Java classloaders in a war application ( jar/classloader hell ) quartz

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, quartz-scheduler

I have a maven project setup such as

```
parent
...pom.xml
...servlet-app 
......pom.xml ( specifies simple-lib as a dependency )
...simple-lib
......src/main/resources/config.properties
......src/main/java/package1/Config.java
......src/main/java/package1/HelloQuartzJob.java
```

basically the servlet application servlet-app specifies simple-lib as a dependency. The config file config.properties is packaged at the top/level of the simple-lib.jar. And when i unpack the servelet-app.war i can see the WEB_INF/lib/simple-lib.jar. So, everything is good.

The Config.java looks like this:

```
public class Config{

    static final String PROPERTILES_FILE = "config.properties";
    static Properties props;
    static{
        log.info("Loading Config properties from {}", PROPERTILES_FILE);
        props = new Properties();

        try {
            InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(PROPERTILES_FILE);
            if (is == null) {
                log.info("Loading through ClassLoader as root");
                is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/"+PROPERTILES_FILE);
            }
            if (is == null) {
                log.info("Loading through Config.class. root");
                is = Config.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+PROPERTILES_FILE);
            }
            if (is == null) {
                log.info("Loading through Config.class. relative");
                is = Config.class.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTILES_FILE);
            }
            if( is == null ) {
                log.info("Thread class loader root");
                is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/"+PROPERTILES_FILE);
            }
            props.load(is);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("Config properties loading error ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But, When I deploy it in tomcat7 I get a NoClassDefFound/Could not initialize package1.Config error. I believe this is because of the classLoaders.

Also of interest is that this package1.Config is used by HelloQuartzJob.java which is a quartz job that is run by the scheduler instance running within this servlet application.

Any pointers?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14433978/597657

Comment: That issue is related but not exactly. In this case my class is not being initialized at all as it cannot find the resource through the class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line:

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(PROPERTILES_FILE);
```

with:

```
InputStream is = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTILES_FILE);
```

in order to use the current webapp classloader with its root at the root of war..

Comment: Its static scope. There is no "this".

Comment: @smartnut007 the idea is still the same, get the classloader of the  class either form this or Config.class, reconsider your downvote.

Comment: I think you are not reading my question fully. I have tried the same above, at least the equivalent Config.class.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTILES_FILE)

Comment: That is not the same. You have to use Config.class.getClassLoader()

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

```
is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/"+PROPERTILES_FILE);
```

and

```
is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/"+PROPERTILES_FILE);
```

---

don't use a leading '/' character when loading resources directly from a classloader.

From `Class.getResourceAsStream()` use a leading '/' (as the resource is loaded relative to the class's package otherwise) but for `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` and `getSystemResourceAsStream()` do *not* use a leading '/'.

Answer (score 0):

You nead to ask for a resource from the classloader instance.

From a static context:

```
String url = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResource("config.properties");
InputStream is = Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

From an instance:

```
String url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config.properties");
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

You should only use relative path and never absolute path (starting with "/") for accessing jar resource in webapp context.

Yesterday I had the same trouble and this way it was easy to solve it :-)

It is just a simle classLoader issue but it is very important. If you use absolute path the loader only looks into the WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: you can read this topic as well https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html